# join/connect two parent's childs elements together with JS

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, foreach, gsap

I have two separate parent elements with child elements like so:

```
<section>
    <div class="projects_name-container">
        <div class="projects_name">
            <a id="child1" href="">child1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="projects_name">
            <a id="child2" href="">child2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="projects_name">
            <a id="child3" href="">child3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="projects_name">
            <a id="child4" href="">child4</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="projects_image-container">
        <div class="image_wrapper">
            <div class="image_mask"><img alt="" src="/img/child1.jpg" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image_wrapper">
            <div class="image_mask"><img alt="" src="/img/child2.jpg" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image_wrapper">
            <div class="image_mask"><img alt="" src="/img/child3.jpg" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image_wrapper">
            <div class="image_mask"><img alt="" src="/img/child4.jpg" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

const worksProjectNames = document.querySelectorAll('.projects_name');
const projectLinks = gsap.utils.toArray('.projects_name a');
const projectImageWrap = document.querySelectorAll('.image_wrapper');
const projectMask = document.querySelectorAll('.image_mask);
const projectImgInside = document.querySelectorAll('.image_mask img');

gsap.set(projectImageBox, { yPercent: -101 });
gsap.set(projectMask, { yPercent: 100 });
gsap.set(projectImgInside, { scale: 1.2 });

worksProjectNames.forEach((project, i) => {   
    
    let splitProjectNames = new SplitText(project, { type:"chars" }),
    projectTitle = splitProjectNames.chars;

    let tl = gsap.timeline({
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: '.works_pg',
            toggleActions: "play reset play reset"    
        }
    });

    tl.from(projectTitle, {
        delay: i * 0.4,
        duration: 1,
        autoAlpha: 0,
        y: 100,
        stagger: {
            amount: 0.3,
        },
        ease: 'power1.out'
    });
});


// Portfolio Hover
function initPortfolioHover() {
    projectLinks.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('mouseenter', createPortfolioHover);
        link.addEventListener('mouseleave', createPortfolioHover);
    });
}
initPortfolioHover();

function createPortfolioHover(e){

    const allSiblings = projectLinks.filter(item => item !== e.target);
    const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { duration: 1.2, ease: 'expo.inOut' } });

    if(e.type === 'mouseenter'){

        tl.to([projectMask, projectImageBox], { yPercent: 0 })
            .to(projectImgInside, { duration: 1.1, scale: 1 }, 0)
            .to(allSiblings, { opacity: 0.2, autoAlpha: 1 }, 0)
            .to(e.target, { opacity: 1, autoAlpha: 1 }, 0);

    } else if(e.type === 'mouseleave'){


        tl.to(projectMas, {yPercent: 100})
            .to(projectImageBox, { yPercent: -101 }, 0)
            .to(projectImgInside, { scale: 1.2 }, 0)
            .to(projectLinks, { opacity: 1, autoAlpha: 1 }, 0);

    }

    return tl;

}
```

I want to "join/link" the child elements together, so that when I hover over ".projects_name" I can animate the elements inside ".image_wrapper". I'm not really sure the correct way to "link" them together in JavaScript, I know how to do the animation part. The ID's are not permeant, I just added to help explain how I'm trying to link them together.  I'm using vanilla JavaScript and GSAP for my animations.

I'm horrible at explaining things with out a visual aid, here is a live site https://www.rudolfson.com/ if you hover the text then the image displays, the text and image are in separate parent containers.

Comment: ids in html *should* be unique. you have child1, child2, child3, child4 ids repeated twice.

Comment: Hey Robbie. You should check out my article about [animating efficiently](https://css-tricks.com/tips-for-writing-animation-code-efficiently/). It shows how to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks @ZachSaucier I just read the article, I was going about it completely wrong but I got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

As @PedroEstrada rightly pointed out, element IDs should be unique. So you need to fix this problem.

There are a number of ways you could link the name fields to the image fields.

1. Use related naming: If the name field ids are like "[field1]name", you could have the image fields use an id/class like "[field1]class"
2. Add an attribute in your name fields that indicate what ids/classes should be animated on hover, like  (I am "borrowing" the "for" attribute from label, but you could use something else like "data")
3. You could do this by index. Figure out the index in the names div, and then link by that index in the image div.

Comment: I'm going to edit my original post and add my Javascript that I already have.